# Backspace in Evernote does not delete words at an even speed

Tags: evernote

In Evernote if I hold down the backspace key too long it deletes way to fast. Worse yet there is not undo option. I have lost many notes this way. Is there a way to change the rate at which the backspace key works (or at least hold the rate constant) or is there an undo key? I think Evernote is great but this is almost a deal breaker because if you loose your notes it doesn't matter how good the other features are.

UPDATE: the fact that the main productivity program for Android lacks even these simple functions was the largest reason I got rid of my tablet.

Comment: Give this feedback to app developer or comment on the Playstore page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a feature request (or defect report) for an app.

Comment: Not really. I'm asking if there is an option to change it. I'm also asking if there's an undo button which certainly isn't a bad question.

Comment: Is it definitely just Evernote? I'd expect the backspace behaviour to be set by the input method (soft keyboard), not the app you're typing into.

Answer (score 0):

## The backspace key

The backspace keep *repeated* action is controlled at application level, either by the keyboard App, the Evernote App or the Android System.

AFAIK, there's no setting to control the spead of the action repeat cycle.

## The undo feature

A premium user of Evernote has a backup privilege that creates a snapshot of every note on the Evernote server every 8 hours.

[HELP: Need to restore text deleted from a note](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/26381-help-need-to-restore-text-deleted-from-a-note/?p=165655)

> Note history creates a snapshot of your not on our server every 8 hours.

Aside from that, there's no undo capabilities on the application.

---

**Note:** As already suggested on the comments under your question, you could submit a feature request to have a *Redo* functionality.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the icon bar with Bold, Italics, Underline, etc. there are icons for Undo and Redo (right-rotating arrow and left-rotating arrow). I only noticed them recently.

I too wonder why the backspace speed speeds up uncontrollably.